# What is an incommensurable grain boundary?

Tags: terminology, material-science, definition, crystals

As the title states, I'm unsure what it means to be a *commensurable* or *incommensurable* grain boundary (when discussing dislocations and small angle grain boundaries). I see the term being used throughout literature.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Side question: are the terms *commensu**rate*** and *commensu**rable*** the same in this context? (**Yes**)

**Update**

In Priester's *Grain Boundaries: From Theory to Engineering*, the definition is stated as follows:

> A symmetrical grain boundary is said commensurable or incommensurable depending on whether a periodicity exists or not in the grain boundary plane, in one direction at least.

Whereas, in Randle's *The Measurement of Grain Boundary Geometry*, the definition is states as:

> Commensurate grain boundary: GB where the ratio of the planar GB unit cells is an integer

I am confused on the relationship between these definitions, and also am unsure of what these *unit cells* are. Are these the basis vectors of the GB plane?

Comment: The first return on a search for 'commensurable "grain boundary"' on Google Books gives a definition from Priester's *Grain Boundaries: From Theory to Engineering*. The same definitions are returned for "commensurate" and "commensurable", indicating that they're used synonymously.

Comment: Thank you for providing that method of searching. I'm still exactly unsure how I would identify a (in)commensurable boundary. The definition in Priester's book is a little vague. I will update the post with what I mean